# Where to get the SDK for Intellij iDEA for Scala?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I've never used Intellij before or even heard of SDK's, but on the page that describes how to setup it says you need an SDK, and in the tutorial it was 1.6 (java version 1.6.0_37). Where do I download or find this? I've looked all over and all I find is a Java JDK version 6, and can't find any references to SDK's at all.

Answer (score 0):

Java version 6 is actually 1.6, so you are right in getting the Java SDK 6. You can really get [Java 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) I would think